# How to find the average given that you have the mean, standard deviation and amount?

Tags: mathematical-statistics

I have an assignment where I'm asked to find the the average shoe number for men and women from given data:

Sum of men and women: 312

Amount of men: 239

Standard deviation of men: 1.63

Mean of shoe number for men: 43.5

Amount of women: 239

Standard deviation of women: 1.4

Mean of shoe number for women: 38.2

Variance squared: 2321

Sum of all shoe numbers: 13183

But I have no idea how to find that using this data. Please help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: ?! Mean of men: 43.5, Mean of women: 38.2 ?!

Comment: It is the mean of the shoe number for men and women

Comment: Isn't that what you want, the average shoe number?

Comment: Yes, I want the average shoe number specifically for men and specifically for women.

Comment: @AlanRostem average and mean are the same thing.

Comment: There is something strange about this question and those numbers need more context. What does sum of men and women mean? Certainly it is not the amount of men plus the amount of women ($239+239 \neq 312$).

Comment: Your numbers make more sense when you consider 73 women. In that case also the sum of all shoe numbers adds up correctly $73 \times 38.2 + 239 \times 43.5 \approx 13183$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want to know the mean and variance of a population given you have these values for different groups of this population, you need to compute what is called [pooled mean and variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pooled_variance).

Given that you already have mean and variance for both groups, I have to assume your question is really for these pooled values, for which the formulas are:

- pooled mean: $\frac{\sum_i^n N_i \mu_i}{\sum_i^n N_i}$
- pooled variance: $\frac{\sum_i^n (N_i-1) \sigma_i^2}{\sum_i^n (N_i-1)}$

$N_i$, $\sigma^2_i$  and $\mu_i$ stand for the number of observations, variance and mean of group $i$, respectively.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. Due to a language barrier I had misunderstood the question which made it much harder for myself than it should have. Thanks for trying to help though I learned a lot today!

Comment: @AlanRostem it is OK, did my answer help you?

Comment: Yes. I used that formula to find the variance then the standard deviation. Thanks!